# tweet object haiku extraction

Tags: python-3.x, twitter

**ANSWER**

The problem was that the `twobj` variable was used before, and got mixed in this part of the code. Everything works now. If you have any questions about my project, feel free to ask anyway.

**PROBLEM**

I am writing a programme which automatically extracts twitter messages from a database that match the haiku pattern (5 syllables, 7 syllables, 5 syllables) and then posts them on twitter. Everything works, except for the syllable count. This filter module, which is supposed to count the syllables, gets an object with a tokenized tweet and checks each word for number of syllables in a dictionary. This dictionary works fine. I set it up with words as keys and number of syllables as values. The problem is I can't manage to write the proper script to check if the number of syllables matches the Haiku pattern. This is my code right now:

```
# twobj_list is a list of tweet objects
for twobj in twobj_list:
    syl_cnt = 0
    line1 = False
    line2 = False
    line3 = False
    haiku_match = True

    # twobj.text is tokenized tweet
    for i in range(len(twobj.text)):

        # dpw_dict is a (dutch) dictionary with words as keys 
        # and number of syllables as values
        if twobj.text[i] in dpw_dict:
            syl_cnt += dpw_dict[twobj.text[i]]
            if not line1 and haiku_match:
                if syl_cnt > 5:
                    haiku_match = False
                elif syl_cnt == 5:
                    line1 = True
            elif not line2 and haiku_match:
                if syl_cnt > 12:
                    haiku_match = False
                elif syl_cnt == 12:
                    line1 = True
            elif not line3 and haiku_match:
                if syl_cnt > 17:
                    haiku_match = False
                elif syl_cnt == 17 and i + 1 == len(twobj.text):
                    line3 = True
                    break
                elif syl_cnt == 17 and not i + 1 < len(twobj.text):
                    haiku_match = False

    if haiku_match:
        new_twobj_list.append(twobj)
```

The line:

```
if twobj.text[i] in dpw_dict:
    syl_cnt += dpw_dict[twobj.text[i]]
```

gives the number of syllables for words in the tweets that match a word in the dictionary. As far as I know, this works.

I hope someone can tell me what I did wrong here. Thanks in advance

The output consists of a number of tweets which do not match the haiku pattern in the slightest way. However, as far as I can see, all of them are shorter than 17 syllables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the `twobj` variable was used before, and got mixed in this part of the code. Everything works now. If you have any questions about my project, feel free to ask anyway.